# How do you make an Ajax call to Google Drive API?

Tags: ajax, google-api, google-drive-api, google-authentication

My code can get an auth2.0 token...but the examples I've found don't show the final piece of taking a GET, provided [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get), and turning it into a working request.

Here is the specific URL from that link:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

Here is my AJAX call with the attempt at getting the token (that works) into a hardcoded fileId that I know my Google account has access to.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + token);
  },
  // url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/18qxc3YgnQ_Yg8n4Q18WCZahE9EPtOZWhoKJuAx6SEHI/permissions",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/18qxc3YgnQ_Yg8n4Q18WCZahE9EPtOZWhoKJuAx6SEHI",
  dataType: 'application/json',
  processData: true,
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log('Got File Metadata: ' + msg) + console.log(msg);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown + ' / ' + textStatus) + console.log(jqXHR);
  }
});
```

I don't understand how to include the token and the pages and pages of Google documentation do not include any examples of going this route.

I get "invalid credential" errors in the server response.

I don't want to use GAPI because I ran into invalid cookie issues running locally and my code is in a Chrome Extension and it isn't clear whether that approach will work there.

Thank you for any help or direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, this line:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + token);
```

You should have a space after Bearer

```
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Comment: Oh my....*&&*^#(*&()$@@~~!@.

Thank you - this got me to basic meta data and a working connection. I'm always amazed at how much time I can burn on syntax vs. actually important stuff.